# SQL update numeric column from decimal datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting

I am trying to update a column of type numeric(5,2) from decimal(10,2) but the column is remaining null and I have no error messages.

```
DECLARE @newDurationAsDec decimal(10,2) 
DECLARE @newDurationAsNum numeric(5,2)

--@newDurationAsDec is set by some logic from another table and holds the correct value e.g 2.00

set @newDurationAsNum = CAST(@newDurationAsDec AS numeric(5,2)) 
--selecting @newDurationAsNum contains the correct value e.g. 2.00

UPDATE table
SET Duration = @newDurationAsNum
WHERE ID = @ID AND
      Duration IS NULL AND
      OtherColumn = 'T'
```

No errors are retruned and the column is not updated. Changing the update to a select returns the correct row. can someone point out my mistake? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the value of `@id`? Are you sure there are matching records?

Comment: Duration IS NULL AND OtherColumn = 'T' => perhaps these criteria are not met?

Comment: Are you sure the filters in your `WHERE` clause match an existing row? Try running a select statement with the same parameters.

Comment: running a select statement with the same parameters returns the correct row

Comment: @5n0u7 - In the messages tab what does it say for rows affected?

Comment: @Martin - it says 1 row(s) affected

Comment: @5n0u7  - Do you have any triggers on the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works fine for me below. Check there are no triggers that might be interfering with things.

If you are on at least SQL Server 2005 you can use the `OUTPUT` clause to see the row(s) updated as illustrated below.

```
CREATE TABLE #T
(
ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
Duration NUMERIC(5,2),
OtherColumn CHAR(1)
)

INSERT INTO #T VALUES (1,NULL,'T')

DECLARE @ID INT = 1
DECLARE @newDurationAsDec DECIMAL(10,2) = 2

DECLARE @newDurationAsNum NUMERIC(5,2)
SET @newDurationAsNum = CAST(@newDurationAsDec AS NUMERIC(5,2)) 
SELECT @newDurationAsNum

UPDATE #T
SET Duration = @newDurationAsNum
OUTPUT inserted.*, deleted.*
WHERE ID = @ID AND
  Duration IS NULL AND
  OtherColumn = 'T'

SELECT * FROM #T  

DROP TABLE #T
```

Answer (score 2):

Run a select to see what you will be updating. I  embed my updates statements as shown below so it is easy to move back and forth from the select to the update just by commenting and uncommenting lines of code

```
--UPDATE t
--SET Duration = @newDurationAsNum 
Select *,   @newDurationAsNum
FROM table t
WHERE ID = @ID AND
       Duration IS NULL AND
       OtherColumn = 'T'
```